# Executing Django + Grunt on same port

Tags: python, django, node.js, gruntjs, spawn

I am newbie in Grunt.
I want to hit the server side code present in my existing Django application.

My Grunt executes on port 2000.
I configured below Grunt task which executes the Django application on port 2000.
Whenever I execute Grunt then it changes its port to 2001.

```
var childExec = require("child_process").exec,
commandRunDjango = "python ../server/manage.py runserver 2000";

childExec(commandRunDjango, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      //callback
});
```

How can I execute the Django and Grunt on same port??

Thank You..

Comment: Under normal conditions, you cannot bind two processes to the same port. You must use different IP Addresses for that to become possible. Try binding one at 127.0.0.1:2000 and another one at 127.0.0.2:2000

Comment: If you want to expose, by the same IP address and port, both services, you must use nginx or another proxy which allows to proxy connections by domain to a different process, but under the hood you you're still using two different ports for the processes (3 in total, if we consider nginx process as well)

Comment: Maybe you should check this out https://github.com/skibblenybbles/django-grunt